# How to shorthand array declaration in a method call?

Tags: c#, vb.net, arrays, syntax

This is hopefully a softball syntax question: I need to call a method with an empty Object array for evaluation and set initial state. In C# I would just do this:

```
func(new Object[]{});
```

In VB.NET I am forced to do this:

```
Dim ctrls() As Control = {}
func(ctrls)
```

Is there a way to shorthand the call in VB.NET and have everything happen in one line of code?

Comment: I think we should bash the author for adding the ps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eerily similar to the C# syntax:

```
func(New Object() { })
```

Comment: Yeah, only two characters off.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
func(New Control() {})
```